# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{1024}\left \lfloor \log_2n \right \rfloor$.

Tags: summation, logarithms

> Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{1024}\left \lfloor \log_2n \right \rfloor$.

I thought the answer is $1+1*2+2*2^2+3*2^3+4*2^4+5*2^5+6*2^6+7*2^7+8*2^8+9*2^9+2^{10}=9219$, but the answer should be 8204. What mistake have I made?

Comment: The first term should be $0 = 0 \cdot 2^0$ and the last term $10$. Then you get 1015 less, that is 8204.

Comment: HAHA! I've just made a stupid mistake! Thanks martini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor = k$ iff $2^k \le n < 2^{k+1}$, so for $0 \le k \le 9$, $k$ appears in the above sum exactly $2^{k+1} - 2^k = 2^k$ times. As $10$ appears exactly once (for $n =1024$), we have
\[
\sum_{n=1}^{1024} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor = 10 + \sum_{k=0}^9 k2^k 
  = 8204.
\]